# Check if audio is playing correctly using Selenium

Tags: html, unit-testing, audio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing tests for an HTML5 game, and I want to check that the audio is loading and starting correctly.

Is there a way to check this using Selenium? or do I need to do this at the OS level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always respond to questions like this with "*Tell me how a human being would check that ...*".  The answer is this case would be to listen to the audio and see if what's supposed to be playing is.  You're not going to be able to make a computer do that easily.

Comment: Selenium doesn't do OS-level anything.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042241/detecting-if-sound-is-playing-in-selenium

I would like to know if a tab is playing audio, the same way that Chrome puts the little speaker icon in the tab.  Is there a way with selenium to detect if that speaker icon is there perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

You could check the [audio element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), after it should've started playing:

```java
WebElement audio = driver.findElement(By.tagName("audio"));
String currentTime = audio.getAttribute("currentTime");
try {
    assertTrue(Double.parseDouble(currentTime) > 0.0);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
    assertEquals(ex, null);
}
```

If it failed to load, or never started, then this test should fail.