# Does a headless browser play audio?

Tags: audio, headless, webautomation

I never used a headless browser and I wondered, if it is possible to drive a site like youtube and play it's audio from a headless browser (e.g. selenium)?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17349345/476716

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I just installed Selenium and I guess, using it headless is not something it does out of the box.

I ask, because I wanted to listen to youtube music without the heavy load of a whole browser.

Comment: [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) and [mpv](https://mpv.io) (which may rely on youtube-dl) are great tools. youtube-dl might have options for audio-only download, and mpv should be able to stream. Search results or playlists can be played too.