# Stop all audio inside iframes from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, iframe

I have one index.html that has several iframes in it.  I am loading a different html page into each iframe when the index.html is launched.  Each html page has multiple audio tags inside them. I use the index.html to navigate between iframes.

Is it possible to have a function in the index that will stop all audio?  I'm having issues with audio stepping on top of each other when i'm want to 'jump' to another iframe before the current one has finished playing audio.  I know how to access the parent index file from the iframe, but how can I target all iframes from the index and stop the audio tags?  I've searched endlessly but haven't found a solution.

Here is the function that I was trying to get to work, but it only seems to catch the audio tag in the index, not the ones inside the iframes.

```
function audioClear(){
    var sounds = window.document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].pause();
};
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I'm still fairly new to working with audio so I'm doing my best.

Comment: run that code  inside the framed page, or iterate the `frames` collection. you can move that code to the framed page's _onunload_ event to make it run when the frame navigates away.

Comment: Can you post the html, please?

Comment: Thank you @dandavis for your suggestion, I was wanting to loop through the iframes but I didn't know how to target them.

Comment: @doutriforce I'm sorry i didn't post the html, but it's my company's code and I cannot post it due to copyrights.  But basically I just had an index with several iframes and then there was navigation code to 'flip' through the iframes.  But when going from one to the next, I could hear audio from the previous 'page', since the iframes were not being unloaded.  So having this function to loop through and pause all the audio worked out well.

Comment: @layerburn, no sweat! Glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do.
It should iterates all frames to find the audios.
Try it.

```
var frames = window.frames;
for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) { 
  var sounds = frames[i].document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
  for(j=0; j<sounds.length; j++){
    sounds[j].pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Now I'm seeing it grab more than the single audio tag, I'm not able to jump between different iframes without audio stepping on each other.  The window.frames was the piece I was missing, thank you so much for your help!  I knew there had to be a way to find them all.