# Detect if <iframe> is playing audio

Tags: javascript, web, audio, iframe, web-deployment

**Question**

I'd like to know whether an `<iframe>` that is embedded in my website is playing audio.

Ideally as well how "loud" the `<iframe>` is playing the audio but that's optional.

Note that the `<iframe>` is not on the same origin, hence inspecting the `<iframe>` is not an option.

**My Concrete Use Case**

I'm the developer of https://www.timer-tab.com/ and when the time is up a YouTube video starts playing. The YouTube video is playing in an `<iframe>`. I'd like to know whether the YouTube `<iframe>` is emitting any sound. If it doesn't emit any sound, a fallback sound is played using the Web Audio API. (The YouTube `<iframe>` sometimes doesn't emit sound. For example, when the user has set his YouTube volume setting to mute. Unfortunately, it is not possible to get that information by `postMessage`ing the YouTube `<iframe>`.)

**Related Question**

[Detect if audio is playing in browser Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632647/detect-if-audio-is-playing-in-browser-javascript).

This is not a duplicated; my question asks specifically for `<iframe>` audio detection whereas the related questions asks for *all audio* detection.

Comment: Is it an option to control the volume yourself? You could if you control the way you embed it.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the API allows it. For security reasons, you cannot.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The only way this is possible is if the content of the iframe were running its own Web Audio graph, with its built-in analyser node, and then relayed to the other frame via postMessage or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question by the title (which I don't think is even possible), but it may solve your underlying problem. You could use **YouTube's JavaScript API** to detect if the audio is muted or just unmute it if desired:

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    console.log("isMuted = " + event.target.isMuted());
    event.target.unMute();
    event.target.setVolume(100);
  }
}
```

```html
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Note that this snippet won't run properly on StackOverflow because it does not allow `iframe` elements. I tested it locally and it worked though.

You can find more information in the documentation ([YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)), such as configuration properties and all the functions available.