# Detect if audio is playing on the website

Tags: javascript, playwright

This is somewhat a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632647/detect-if-audio-is-playing-in-browser-javascript), but I do not understand on how to use the accepted answer. Furthermore the question is quite old and maybe there is a better way available now.

#### My use case:

I want to test if audio in general is playing with Playwright. The audio source is not a DOM-Element, so checking media elements is not a solution.

This is how the code would get used:

```js
const isAudioPlaying = page.evaluate(() => {
    /* Code goes here */
})
```

Edit:
And this is how the code of the media playback looks like in its most simple form:

```js
function createAudioPlayer() {
    const audio = new Audio()

    return {
      setSource: (src) => audio.src = src,
      play: () => audio.play,
      pause: () => audio.pause,
      resume: () => audio.resume,
    }
}
```

This factory just uses the default Audio constructor for the playback. It never touches the DOM like that.

Comment: What is the audio source; can you share some code to share what you're trying to detect? The obvious solution would seem to be `const audioPlaying = navigator.mediaSession.playbackState !== 'none';` but I have no idea whether that might work in your particular use-case.

Comment: @DavidThomas I added a code example. Unluckily `navigator.mediaSession.playbackState` does not seem to work in this case. If there is not other way though, I will probably just add a hidden audio element to the page, just to get it working

Comment: I tested it a bit more and it does not seem that `mediaSession` provides this functionality. Instead it needs to get set programmatically manually.

Comment: What about [`mediaElement.paused` and `mediaElement.ended`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-media-paused-dev)? They can't be true if the audio is playing. So checking if both are false would mean that the media-element is playing or loading/buffering. The HTML Audio Element inherits this properties, so you can check for `!audio.ended && !audio.paused`

Comment: @Christopher I decided to do something like that, but it only works with elements loaded into the dom (so I just added an invisible player for that). 
The question itself though is for getting the overall audio playback, not restricted to the dom