# How to detect if any sound is played in any website, using JS?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way, using JS, to make any website display a message if a sound is played? For instance, if I'm on Facebook, when a notification sound is played, I want to intercept this sound and run any code I want via JS.

Something like the code below. I would open the website and inject the code below using dev tools.

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (soundPlayed) alert('A sound has played');
};
```

Comment: I don't believe it is possible

Comment: You would have to hook an awful lot of code to detect this.  Are you making a browser extension?  You might be able to use the extension methods around audio session instead.

Comment: You probably could see if any element has used one of the media events listed here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp but not a 100 percent sure way because people can utilize custom events.

Comment: Are you talking client side code on your website? If so no it is not possible. Are you talking a browser extension? If so, that sounds doable. Are you talking NodeJS (doesn't appear so due to the example but anyways)? If so that is going to probably be **very** difficult but theoretically possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if audio is playing in browser Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632647/detect-if-audio-is-playing-in-browser-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (navigator.mediaSession.playbackState === "playing") {...}
```

This checks if audio is playing in the current page or not. Currently its not supported in every browser, but it's supported in most ([read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession/playbackState#browser_compatibility))

If you plan on putting this if check in the console of a webpage and need it to run multiple times I suggest using `SetTimeout`

I tried this on Linux Firefox

*original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60684736/16008501)*

Comment: Actually this works, but problem is, i would check constantly , using setInterval. I'm looking for something like a callback

Comment: Well I couldn't find anything like that, but you could make setInterval run a seperate function and that functions like a callback